# How do I prevent jQuery's insertAfter() method from duplicating the HTML that I'm moving?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on the following page: http://partyz.ourers.com/items/dunk_tank

Below is a recording where I reload the page and open the inspector tool. I hover over the element I'm trying to relocate and then I show where I'm moving the element to in the DOM. Afterwords, I open the console and enter the jQuery to actually move the element:

```
var tabs = $(".tab-content");
tabs.detach();
tabs.insertAfter(".store .legacy-item-page > .row");
```

As soon as I enter this, the element is duplicated even though there is only one .row that it can be inserted after. How do I just move the element rather than duplicating it when it's moved?

http://recordit.co/nSDYRUxxSr

Edit: I tried creating a codepen but couldn't replicate the problem

Comment: But there are multiple `$(".tab-content")` . Not really clear what you are trying to do. Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces problem along with a better explanation of expectations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pointing that out guys. Basically, I just realized the third-party platform I'm using is working on a restructured product page and instead of replacing the old HTML with the new HTML, they are printing both the old and new code into their own respective divs with .legacy-item-page set to display:none and .item-page set to display:block;. This was a recent change that they made and didn't warn anyone of and I only noticed because of the duplication issue. As @Kodie Grantham mentioned, making the selectors more specific will fix the issue I was having.

Comment: Glad I could be of help! If you could, mark my answer as the accepted answer so that I get the rep points on my profile. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two DIV's with the class `tab-content`. Making your first selector a little more specific fixes your issue.

```
var tabs = $(".store .legacy-item-page .tab-content");
tabs.detach();
tabs.insertAfter(".store .legacy-item-page > .row");
```